# Machine Learning Email Prioritization - Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, ranking, scikit-learn

I have been working on a Python coded priority email inbox, with the ultimate aim of using a machine learning algorithm to label (or classify) a selection of emails as either important or un-important. I will begin with some background information and then move into my question.

I have so far developed code to extract data from an email and process it to discover the most important ones. This is achieved using the following email features:

- Senders Address Frequency
- Thread Activity
- Date Received (time between replies)
- Common Words in body/subject

The code I have currently applies a ranking (or weighting) (value 0.1-1) to each email based on its importance and then applies a label of either ‘important’ or ‘un-important’ (In this case this is just 1 or 0). The status of priority is awarded if the rank is >0.5.  This data is stored in a CSV file (as below).

```
     From           Subject       Body        Date          Rank    Priority 
     test@test.com  HelloWorld    Body Words  10/10/2012    0.67    1
     rest@test.com  ByeWorld      Body Words  10/10/2012    0.21    0
     best@test.com  SayWorld      Body Words  10/10/2012    0.91    1
     just@test.com  HeyWorld      Body Words  10/10/2012    0.48    0
     etc        …………………………………………………………………………
```

I have two sets of email data (One Training, One Testing). The above applies to my training email data. I am now attempting to train a learning algorithm so that I can predict the importance of the testing data.

To do this I have been looking at both SCIKIT and NLTK. However, I am having trouble transferring the information I have learnt in the tutorials and implementing into my project. I have no particular requirements in regards to which learning algorithm is used. Is this as simple as applying the following? And if so how?

```
   X, y = email.data, email.target

   from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
   clf = LinearSVC()

   clf = clf.fit(X, y)

   X_new = [Testing Email Data]

   clf.predict(X_new)
```

Comment: I've never used scikit.learn before, but it could indeed be that "simple" to use a classifier once you clean up your data and get your feature vectors. The algorithm in your example seems to be an SVM classifier. You might want to check the features vector format that scikit.learn SVM expects.  



Just a remark: you might not want to include the "Rank" in your feature, since the information about it is encoded already in "Priority" label that you assign (i.e. that's your target variable).

Comment: So for example, my features could be:
Senders Address Frequency
    Thread Activity
    Date Received (time between replies)
    Common Words in body/subject

And the target class to predict:
  Priority

Comment: Yes, that's right. Also make sure that they're all numerical, i.e. consists of numbers (float, int).

Comment: If your current code can rank emails based on their features, it's a classifier already. Why you need to train another one?

Comment: Im looking at comparing different existing classifiers

Comment: Yeah, that's nice. However, your target values (or labels, important/unimportant) are obtained via the current classifier you use. So every label is biased (not ground truth). How should you evaluate the classification error then? I mean You might want to label your email importance manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (though probably not the fastest) solution(*) is to use scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer`. First, read in each sample with Python's `csv` module, and build a `dict` containing `(feature, value)` pairs, while keeping the priority separate:

```
# UNTESTED CODE, may contain a bug or two; also, you need to decide how to
# implement split_words
datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
dicts = []
y = []

for row in datareader:
    y.append(row[-1])
    d = {"From": row[0]}
    for word in split_words(row[1]):
        d["Subject_" + word] = 1
    for word in split_words(row[2]):
        d["Body_" + word] = 1
    # etc.
    dicts.append(d)

# vectorize!
vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(dicts)
```

You now have a sparse matrix `X_train` that, together with `y`, you can feed to a scikit-learn classifier.

Be aware:

1. When you want to make predictions on unseen data, you must apply the same procedure and *the exact same `vectorizer`* object to it. I.e. you have to build a `test_dicts` object using the loop above, then do `X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_dicts)`.
2. I've assumed you want to predict the priority directly. Predicting the "rank" instead would be a regression problem, rather than a classification one. Some scikit-learn classifiers have a `predict_proba` method which will produce the probability that email are important, but you can't train those on the ranks.

(*) I am the author of scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer`, so this is not unbiased advice. It is from the horse's mouth, though :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am implementing, however if the CSV data is already split by word in the CSV file. I presume i would not require 'split_words' so would this line then be 'for word in row[1]?

Comment: @ZeeeeeV You'd still need to split the field somehow, since it will come in as a single string.

Comment: Ok thanks, i have included this now. I am able to successfully feed the data into a scikit-learn classifier and predict. However, if i wanted to use 70% of my data for training and 30% for testing, would this be possible? I imagine i would get an error where X is expecting more features per sample when predicting the 30% ?

Comment: @ZeeeeeV If you process the test set using the vectorizer that was fitted on the training set, then there's no problem: features that did not occur in the training set will just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Another library you may want to take a look at: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/textmining/1.0 
(I've used it in the past)

Answer (score 0):

Can you demonstrate how you developed code to extract data from an email and process it to discover the most important ones.

Senders Address Frequency
Thread Activity
Date Received (time between replies)
Common Words in body/subject